# Is a directed complete graph Hamiltonian? (if there are no sink groups)

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, directed-graphs

For some graph G that is complete (Kn) and directed (every edge ab can be traversed in only one way, either a -> b, or b -> a) and has no sink groups. Is G necessarily Hamiltonian? If so why?

Define a sink group as a group O such that every edge traveling from O' to O is directed into O and there are no edges directed out of ANY vertex O to O' (where O' is G\O, representing all the vertices and edges not in our sink group O).

I understand this requires a complicated proof, the full proof is not necessary, just the key points, thank you!

Comment: In more usual terminology, you are asking whether every **tournament** (**oriented** complete graph) which is **strongly connected** (for any two vertices $x$ and $y$ there is a directed path from $x$ to $y$) has a directed Hamiltonian cycle. The answer is yes, and the proof is not very complicated. Consider a directed cycle of maximum length, and assume for a contradiction that it does not include all the vertices . . .

Comment: (Whereas a "complete directed graph" usually refers to the graph including both edges $a \to b$ and $b \to a$ for any two vertices $a$ and $b$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple directed graph with at least two vertices such that each pair of distinct vertices are connected by a directed edge (in one direction only), and such that no nonempty proper subset of $V$ is a sink.

Let $n=|V|$.

We want to show that $G$ has a cycle of length $n$.

Let $p_1,...,p_k\in V$ be such that $p_1...p_k$ is a path of maximum length.

Since $\{p_k\}$ is not a sink, it follows $k > 2$ and, for some vertex $v$, there is an edge from $p_k$ to $v$.

By maximality of $k$, it follows that $v\in \{p_1,...,p_{k-2}\}$, hence $G$ has a cycle.

Let $a_1...a_ma_1$ be a cycle of maximum length.

Necessarily, $m\ge 3$.

If $m=n$, we're done, so assume $m < n$.

Our goal is to derive a contradiction.

Let $A=\{a_1,...,a_m\}$.

Let $B=\{b\in V{\setminus}A{\,\large{\mid}\,}ab\;\text{is an edge for some}\;a\in A\}$.

Since $A$ is not a sink, $B \ne {\large{\varnothing}}$.

Let $b\in B$.

By maximality of $m$, if $a_i\in A$ is such that $a_ib$ is an edge, then $a_{i+1}b$ is also an edge (where $a_{m+1}$ is interpreted as $a_1$), else we can enlarge the cycle $a_1...a_ma_1$ by replacing $a_ia_{i+1}$ with $a_iba_{i+1}$.

It follows that $ab$ is an edge for all $a\in A$.

Let $C=V{\setminus}(A\cup B)$.

Since $B$ is not a sink, it follows that $C\ne {\large{\varnothing}}$, and moreover, $bc$ is an edge for some $b\in B$ and some $c\in C$.

Since $c\not\in A\cup B$, it follows that $ca$ is an edge for all $a\in A$.

In particular, $ca_2$ is an edge.

But then we have edges $a_1b,bc,ca_2$, hence $a_1bca_2...a_ma_1$ is a cycle of length $m+2$, contrary to the maximality of $m$.

Comment: Perfect! I appreciate the maximality contradiction, the part about C I was unable to place so thank you for explaining it so well!